# Get scene changes for cropped portion of video in a single command

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I would like to do something like this:

```
'ffmpeg -i "video.ts" -vf "crop=768:126:0:400 , 
select=gt(scene\\,0.06) " -vsync vfr  -f null /dev/null -loglevel debug 
2>&1 | grep select:1'
```

However this gives me wrong results as compared to cropping the video in the first command

```
ffmpeg  -i "video.ts" -vf "crop=768:126:0:400" cropped.ts
```

and then taking out the scene changes in the second command.

```
ffmpeg -i "cropped.ts" -vf "select=gt(scene\\,0.06) " -vsync vfr  -f null 
/dev/null -loglevel debug 2>&1 | grep select:1'
```

Is there a single line command which could crop a particular portion of the video and get scene changes only for the cropped portion?

Comment: `select` in the first command only sees the cropped portion.

Comment: Then why is it I am getting different answers?

Comment: Because your 2nd command re-encodes the video. Since the output format is MPEG-TS and no encoder or encoding parameters are set, ffmpeg chooses mpeg2video with a bitrate of 200 kbps. :(. This will destroy the texture detail of large videos and yield different scene scores.

Comment: That was info I could not get anywhere on the net :) But please could you tell me the correct way to do it in a single line? (just found you are among official coders maintaining ffmpeg) thanks for the swift response :)

Comment: The first command is fine.